# how to convert '2016-06-10 09:30:04.000' to '06/10/2016 9:30 AM' in SQL?

Tags: sql, datetime, time

how to convert this format '2016-06-10 09:30:04.000' into '06/10/2016  9:30 AM' this format in SQL.

Comment: Hover your cursor over the `SQL` tag that you added to your question.  After reading the tool tip, please edit your question to specify which DBMS you are using.  Then specify if you are trying to change the contents of the table *(which would mis-understand how date datatypes work)* or if this is just for formatting in the output of a query.

Comment: If you're using the appropriate date types (`datetime` or `datetime2`), they don't **have** a format. They store the number of intervals that have elapsed since some fixed point in the past. When you see things like `2016-06-10 09:30:04.000`, realise that some *string conversion* has been applied to that value in order to make it *displayable* to you. But it is *not* what's actually stored.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: In Oracle and Postgres you would convert the input string to a timestamp then use `to_char()` to format it as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if your database is SQL Server

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),CONVERT(DATE,'2016-06-10 09:30:04.000'),101)+' '+ 
 CAST(CONVERT(varchar(25),CAST(RIGHT('2016-06-10 09:30:04.000',12) AS TIME),100) AS VARCHAR)
```